# How to refactor consecutive, independent, if statements in this algorithm?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, refactoring

The following method generates 81 `Cell` objects that each have their distinct `row`, `column`, and `blocks`. It uses an algorithm that changes those attributes based on the `Cell` that's currently be generated.

The `1.times do` portion is implemented to skip that block of `if` statements on the first loop inside the `until` loop, when the `cell_counter` is 0. How do I make this more elegant?

```
def initialize_default_cells
    cell_counter, row, column = 0,0,0
    block = 1

    until cell_counter == 81
      1.times do 
        break if cell_counter == 0
        if cell_counter % 1 == 0
          column += 1
        end
        if cell_counter % 3 == 0
          block += 1
        end
        if cell_counter % 9 == 0
          column -= 9
          row += 1
          block -= 3
        end
        if cell_counter % 27 == 0
          block += 3
        end
      end
      @cells << Cell.new(ROW_ID[row], COLUMN_ID[column], block)
      cell_counter += 1
    end
  end
```

Comment: Questions about refactoring/improving working code belong on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concluded that it was easiest to calculate `row`, `column` and `block` from scratch for each `i = 0,..,80`.

```
def initialize_default_cells
  (0..80).each do |i|
    @cells << Cell.new(ROW_ID[i/9], COLUMN_ID[i%9], 1 + (i%9)/3 + 3*(i/27))
  end
end
```

The key for `COLUMN_ID` (`i%9`) is reduced from `i-9*(i/9)` and the last argument (`1 + (i%9)/3 + 3*(i/27)`) is reduced from `1 + i/3 - 3*(i/9) + 3*(i/27)`

Consider three examples.

`i=0`

```
@cells << Cell.new(ROW_ID[0/9], COLUMN_ID[0%9], 1 + (0%9)/3 + 3*(0/27))
  #=> << Cell.new(ROW_ID[0], COLUMN_ID[0], 1)
```

`i=6`

```
@cells << Cell.new(ROW_ID[6/9], COLUMN_ID[6%9], 1 + (6%9)/3 + 3*(6/27))
  #=> << Cell.new(ROW_ID[0], COLUMN_ID[6], 3)
```

`i=29`

```
@cells << Cell.new(ROW_ID[29/9], COLUMN_ID[29%9], 1 + (29%9)/3 + 3*(29/27))
  # << Cell.new(ROW_ID[3], COLUMN_ID[2], 4)
```

When `i=6`, `6/3 #=> 2` is the number of positive numbers that are divisible by `3`, `6/9 #=> 0` is the number of positive numbers that are divisible by `9` and  `6/27 #=> 0` is the number of positive numbers that are divisible by `27`. The arguments of `Cell::new` are then computed with these values.

Comment: Instead of `i-9*(i/9)`, might I suggest `i % 9`?

Comment: Also, `i/3 - 3*(i/9)` is `(i % 9)/3`.

Comment: Thanks, @Jordan. I've implemented both suggestions.

Comment: This is so brilliant and elegant. How do you come up with this? I'm definitely going to remember this technique of using i/9, i%9, but that last one is quite difficult to remember. Is there even a term for that? You know any resources that I can read up on that stuff? Did you trial and error in your console many times to refine the output?

Comment: Also, it should be (0..80). I'm guessing you started with (1..81), and forgot to account for the change. It's funny I tested both the method I had originally and with this shorter one, the solver still takes about the save time (down to the tenth of a second) to calculate the solution for the hardest puzzle in the world. I'm guessing that this sort of refactoring is only vital for large apps with a lot of requests at the same time. Thanks Cary.

Comment: Ka, `i%9` is read "i modulo 9". It's wasn't hard to do. It's just a matter of counting occurrences. No trial and error. My code always works the first time. I changed `81` to `80`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Ka, do you believe everything I said in my previous comment?